# is there any alternative for AppLaud Cloud?

Tags: cordova, cloud

I was using the AppLaud Cloud service but now it is close, is there any alternative or similar service out there? I have been looking around with no luck

I loved that service because I was able to run my PhoneGap apps right away on my android phone with no need of messing around with repositories, commits, compilers and publications, just changing the code online then save it and done, it was updated on my phone true their app, that was all!!! it was amazing!, now I'm stuck with same problems as before :(

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out what [Remy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/) did. Here is a video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsmJq7tU_2o

You download his [PhoneGapBin](https://build.phonegap.com/apps/185555) app and hook it up to your [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/welcome/1/edit) account where you can edit your code on the JsBin site.